# Multiple button in Django: Accept and Reject

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-views

I am new to Django. I am working on a project where I want accept and reject button and whenever client click on the respective button that object will go into the accept or reject template. I have no idea how can I do this.

This is my .html file which is displaying all the objects and have a accept and reject button:

```
<div class="body table-responsive">
                        <form id="form" method="POST" action = "{% url 'admin_team_detail' %}">
                                    {% csrf_token %}
                            <table class="table table-hover">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>S No.</th>
                                        <th>COMPANY NAME</th>
                                        <th>TEAM MEMBER</th>
                                        <th>EMAIL</th>
                                        <th>STATUS</th>
                                        <th><center>#</center></th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>

                                        {%for team in object%}
                                    <tr>

                                        <th scope="row"> {{ forloop.counter }}</th>
                                        <td>{{team.company_name}}</td>
                                        <td>{{team.team_member}}</td>
                                        <td>{{team.email}}</td>
                                        <td>-</td>
                                        <td><center><input type="submit" value="accept" name="accept">
                                            <input type="submit" value="reject" name="reject"></center></td> 
                                    </tr>

                                    {% endfor %}

                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </form>
```

Here is views.py:

```
def admin_team_detail(request):
obj= Create_Team.objects.all()
print(request.method)
if request.method == 'POST':
    if 'reject' in request.POST :
        Create_Team.status = 'reject'
    else:
        Create_Team.status = 'accept'
        Create_Team.save()
return render(request, "admin/team-details.html", {"object": obj})
```

This is rendering all the objects from database and displaying on the website.

I know that I have to make two templates for accept and reject but I don't know how it will take the objects that have a accept or reject response.

And I also want that if client click on the button then that response will be saved in the database.

And I also want to know that whether I have to add a field in my model.py for status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First your two buttons should send the desired value to your `views.py` and one hidden input in order to pass the team id

```
<input type="submit" value="reject" name="status">
<input type="submit" value="accept" name="status">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value={{ team.id }}>
```

Next, in your `views.py`

```
def admin_team_detail(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
    # First, you should retrieve the team instance you want to update
        team = Create_Team.objects.get(id=request.POST('id'))

        # Next, you update the status
        if request.POST.get('status'):
            team.status = request.POST.get('status')
            team.save()
```

Note: this example assumes your Team model has a status field in order to store the reject/accept value.

```
class Team(models.Model):
    # You existing fields...
    status = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

Comment: ok so i have to add a status field in my model but i have a question how i can be added means:  Status {'accept' = 'accept',  'reject' = 'reject' }    or    status = model.textfield which is correct.

Comment: Check the doc about [models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/) to learn how models works. I have edited my answer considering this.

Comment: i have edited my views but it contain an error saying : " save() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' "

Comment: In your views.py `Create_Team` does not refer to anything. As mentionned in my initial snippet : First, you should retrieve the team instance you want to update

Comment: it is doing something different in the database,  it is making a default object in the database that only contains the status field filled and all other fields are blank...

Comment: See my code, you should pass the team id trough the form and use to retrieve your instance.

Comment: Hi @SahilSharma if this answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

First You need to create a form for each object inside the template.

```
{%for team in object%}
  <form method="POST">
      {%csrf_token%}
    <input type="hidden" name="team_id" value={{ team.id }}>
    <input type="submit" value="reject" name="status">
    <input type="submit" value="accept" name="status">
  </form>
{% endfor %}
```

Now in View.py, you need to do something like this:

```
def admin_team_detail(request):

if request.method == 'POST':
    # I am assuming Create_Team is your model where all team's are present.
    team = Create_Team.objects.get(id=request.POST.get("team_id"))
        team.status = request.POST.get("status")
        team.save()
```

Comment: dude can you explain what is team_id here.

Comment: you can see i have edited my template now can you tell me where i am lacking

Comment: @pavan kumar it's not updating the status in my database

Comment: @pavan kumar   you can see where you are lacking as you are on the track but have reached only half way i have accepted an answer that works for me..